# JQuery - addClass() not working for IE10+

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have created a javascript function which fades in a number of elements when the page is scrolled down to a specific point. This is done by adding the class "active" (with addClass) to the relevant elements which would then fade them in via CSS.

On IE10+ JQuery addClass() does not appear to work. I am stumped as to why!

```
    var fadeServiceList = function(sT, wH) {
        var $home_why_us = $('.home-why-us'),
            $theshold = $home_why_us.offset().top;

        if (sT > $theshold - ( wH / 2 ) ) {
            $('#line').addClass('active');
            $home_why_us.find('.service-list ul').addClass('active');
        }
    };
```

I would appreciate your help pointing me in the right direction!

Cheers,
Jim.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the line gets called to add the class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am positive that it is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 11 (possibly other versions) ignores the first application of .addClass() if the target element:
is one of the following inline elements: label, strong, span, em
contains an input element (any type)
contains text within another inline element such as: label, strong, span, em
It behaves properly in other browsers.

```
function highlight(){
    $("label").addClass("highlight");
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r6SVH/2/)

Comment: Hi, have you got a link to documentation? I gave this a try in IE 11 and it worked.